# How can one force Log4php to reload the config file in a PHP CLI daemon

Tags: php, log4php

In a Linux daemon running a PHP CLI that uses Log4php, how can I force log4php to reload the XML config file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess by calling `Logger::config()` again. But could you tell us why you need it? I think re-configuring has some side effects that should be considered.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a great idea, I've abandoned this course of action